# Backbone collection.create makes both post and put requests

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

When using collection.create passing in a simple object and using wait:true I am seeing a behaviour where there is an initial POST as expected but it is then followed up by an additional PUT. The rest-like server is returning status 200 and an object that has slightly more items in it (such as an _id, some empty arrays).

Is this expected standard behaviour or have I broken something?

Comment: please share your collection code so we can help.

Comment: If you want to write and answer along those lines ill accept it :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Wow Scott Puleo suggested that I paste my code and I found this:

```
class collections.Projects extends Backbone.Collection
"url": "/api/projects"
"model":models.Project

"initialize": ->
    @on "add", (_project) ->
        jqXHR = _project.save()
        #console.log "jqXHR: ", jqXHR
        #jqXHR.done (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
            #console.log "saved: ", _project
```

That's a nasty code snipplet and no idea what I was thinking months ago when I wrote that. Thanks for your help.